# wp-admin blank in a clean install of Wordpress on PHP 5.4

Tags: wp-admin, fatal-error

A clean install of Wordpress 3.4.2 is giving a blank screen when logging into the admin panel. This is due to the following resources not loading in Chrome:

```
GET /wp-admin/  /wp-admin/:32
GET /wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load=wp-jquery-ui-dialog&ver=3.4.2  /wp-admin/:32
GET /wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load=jquery,utils&ver=3.4.2  /wp-admin/:32
GET /wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load=admin-bar,wp-admin&ver=3.4.2  /wp-admin/:26
GET /wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load=admin-bar,hoverIntent,common,jquery-color,wp-ajax-response,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,dashboard,thickbox,plugin-install,media-upload,word-count,jquery-ui-resizable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-button,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-dialog,wpdialogs,wplink,wpdialogs-popup&ver=3.4.2  /wp-admin/:32
```

However, visiting these links directly returns the contents as normal.

There are no entries in Apache's error log for this.

I have found that if I add the following line just before `echo $out;` in **wp-admin/load-scripts.php** and **load-styles.php**, the page loads the assets correctly, aside from TinyMCE:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($out));
```

Similarly, if I add the following line to my `wp-config.php` the admin panel loads correctly (as it bypasses **load-X.php**):

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

Content does display correctly in Firefox however.

**Is this a bug?** If so, is the issue already known?

---

The only oddities about my setup are that I am running PHP version `5.4.8-1~precise+1`, obtained from [Ondřej's](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5) PPA, on Apache/2.2.22 (on Ubuntu).

The most common suggestion seems to be that it is a problem with my configuration, rather than Wordpress - my Apache install is fairly standard, the VirtualHost for this blog configured as so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/www/wordpress/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/www/wordpress/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The Wordpress install has no extra themes, plugins and whatnot. It is a simple download from Wordpress.org that has been configured using the installer.

Comment: You usually need `AllowOveride All` if it isn't configured globally. I don't know if that is your problem. Does PHP's [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) work in other contexts on your server?

Comment: 'There are no entries in Apache's error log for this.' What entries are in the log? Any entry is relevant at this point.

Comment: [Please improve your error output like I show in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/4063197). Then report back with the shown errors.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I've added that but don't see any effect. There aren't actually any .htaccess files in the installed download - should there be?

Comment: @Stephen The only entries in the error log are for a missing favicon.

Comment: @kaiser I had most of those active already, but nothing is displayed or written to `wp-content/debug.log`.

Comment: Take a look at your PHP settings (phpinfo()) and see if anything stands out to you. Maybe increase your PHP memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a root to the problem. I recently upgraded PHP from apt and unbeknownst to me it now uses apache2filter rather than apache2.

Not entirely sure what triggered that, but it's not how I set it up. Switching over to nginx for example works fine (it also fixes an issue with xmlrpc.php not loading) - so the problem is with apache2filter's default configuration. Sorry for a bogus question!